# Brother DCP-9015CDW prints blank pages with one or two short black lines at the top of every printed page (missing driver?)

Tags: drivers, printing, brother, additional-drivers

Brother DCP-9015CDW prints blank pages with one or two short black lines at the top of every printed page.

How can I fix it? I'm using Ubuntu 17.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a driver for your printer.

1. Go to [the Brother website](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=dcp9015cdw_eu) to get the driver.
2. Choose **Linux** (as OS Family) and **Linux (deb)** (as OS Version) and click **Search**.
3. You want to download the **Driver Install Tool** so click the **Click to choose** link there and then **English** in the pop-up.
4. You'll be prompted to agree to the EULA. Click **Agree to the EULA and Download**.
5. Your browser should now begin to download the **linux-brprinter-installer-2.1.1-1.gz** file.
6. Open up your terminal and  enter the following commands:

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   # Unpack the downloaded archive.
   gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-*.gz
   # Run the tool.
   bash linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-* DCP-9015CDW
   ```

   You'll be asked to provide the URI of your printer. This is how I got the URI myself:

   - Open the **Printers** application.
   - Right-click on your printer there (my Ubuntu has already configured it although it was missing drivers) and open **Properties**.
   - You can see your printer's URI in **Settings** > **Device URI**.

---

Works on Debian "stretch" 9.3 as well.